# how to make a vector of Trait with different Associated Type?

Tags: rust

let's say, I have a following trait:

```rust
pub trait Task {
    type Type;
    fn run(&self, controller: &Controller) -> Result<Self::Type, String>;
}
```

how do I make a vector of `Task` with different `Type`?

---

More detailed, I have a MatchTask implemented this trait:

```rust
impl Task for MatchTask {
    type Type = Rect;
    fn run(&self, controller: &Controller) -> Result<Self::Type, String> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And I also have some other Task which has `Type = ()`.

Now I want to create `AndTask` and `OrTask` (for these two `Task`, I only care about whether it is success or not, so the `Type` for them are both `()`):

```rust
pub struct AndTask {
    tasks: Vec<MatchTask>,
}

impl AndTask {
    pub fn new(tasks: Vec<MatchTask>) -> Self {
        Self { tasks }
    }
}

impl Task for AndTask {
    type Type = ();
    fn run(&self, controller: &Controller) -> Result<Self::Type, String> {
        self.tasks
            .iter()
            .map(|task| task.run(controller).map(|_| ())
            .collect()
    }
}

// OrTask is kind of like that
```

This works, but what if I want to support combination of AndTask and OrTask and more other `Task`? How to make the `Vec` store different kind of `Task`? If I write `Vec<Box<dyn Task>>`, it will say the value of the associated type `Type` in `Task` must be specified.

Comment: What will be the `Type` for `AndTask` with different `Type`s?

Comment: Well, I think it can only be `()`, I've modified the AndTask code in my question.

Comment: Do you need access to the returned `Type`? If yes, it cannot be `()`.

Comment: For `AndTask` and `OrTask`, I only care about whether it is success or not, and for other `Task`s, I may need to access to the returned `Type`.

Answer (score 1):

The associated type makes `Task<Type = ()>` and `Task<Type = Rect>` two completely incompatible types. They cannot be put in a vector together; they are like `i32` and `String`. They have nothing in common, from the perspective of the compiler.

The main problem here is that associated types are **compile time information**, but which element in a vector has which type is **runtime information**. Those two are to some extend convertible into each other with things like `enum`s, but it's not straight forward.

There are two ways I can think of:

- Remove the associated type from the `Task` trait and return an enum instead
- Store the items in the vector as an enum containing boxes.

Both are not really elegant and will require a `match` case somewhere. But that is expected; `match` is what can convert runtime information to compile time information. Which is exactly what we need.

Here is one possible solution using an enum return value:

```rust
pub struct Controller;
pub struct Rect;
pub struct MatchTask;

pub enum TaskResult {
    Rect(Rect),
    Empty,
}

pub trait Task {
    fn run(&self, controller: &Controller) -> Result<TaskResult, String>;
}

impl Task for MatchTask {
    fn run(&self, controller: &Controller) -> Result<TaskResult, String> {
        let result = Rect;
        Ok(TaskResult::Rect(result))
    }
}

pub struct AndTask {
    tasks: Vec<Box<dyn Task>>,
}

impl AndTask {
    pub fn new(tasks: Vec<Box<dyn Task>>) -> Self {
        Self { tasks }
    }
}

impl Task for AndTask {
    fn run(&self, controller: &Controller) -> Result<TaskResult, String> {
        self.tasks
            .iter()
            .map(|task| {
                task.run(controller).map(|result| match result {
                    // Do something with the inner results
                    TaskResult::Rect(_) => (),
                    TaskResult::Empty => (),
                })
            })
            .collect::<Result<(), _>>()
            .map(|()| TaskResult::Empty)
    }
}
```

Or something like this:

```rust
pub struct Controller;
pub struct Rect;
pub struct MatchTask;

pub enum TaskResult {
    Rect(Rect),
    Empty,
}

pub trait Task {
    type Type;
    fn run(&self, controller: &Controller) -> Result<Self::Type, String>;
}

pub enum AbstractBoxedTask {
    Empty(Box<dyn Task<Type = ()>>),
    Rect(Box<dyn Task<Type = Rect>>),
}

impl Task for MatchTask {
    type Type = Rect;
    fn run(&self, controller: &Controller) -> Result<Rect, String> {
        let result = Rect;
        Ok(result)
    }
}

pub struct AndTask {
    tasks: Vec<AbstractBoxedTask>,
}

impl AndTask {
    pub fn new(tasks: Vec<AbstractBoxedTask>) -> Self {
        Self { tasks }
    }
}

impl Task for AndTask {
    type Type = ();
    fn run(&self, controller: &Controller) -> Result<(), String> {
        self.tasks
            .iter()
            .map(|task| match task {
                AbstractBoxedTask::Empty(task) => task.run(controller),
                AbstractBoxedTask::Rect(task) => task.run(controller).map(|_| ()),
            })
            .collect()
    }
}
```

There are many possible solutions, you might have to experiment a little to see which one fits your use-case best.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an adapter that will transform the `Type` to `()`:

```rust
pub struct EraseTypeTask<T>(T);
impl<T: Task> Task for EraseTypeTask<T> {
    type Type = ();
    fn run(&self, controller: &Controller) -> Result<Self::Type, String> {
        self.0.run(controller).map(|_result| ())
    }
}

pub struct AndTask {
    tasks: Vec<Box<dyn Task<Type = ()>>>,
}

impl AndTask {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self { tasks: Vec::new() }
    }

    pub fn add_task(&mut self, task: impl Task + 'static) {
        self.tasks.push(Box::new(EraseTypeTask(task)));
    }
}

impl Task for AndTask {
    type Type = ();
    fn run(&self, controller: &Controller) -> Result<Self::Type, String> {
        self.tasks.iter().map(|task| task.run(controller)).collect()
    }
}
```